# Executing Shell Script via Automator

Tags: r, macos, shell, automator

via Terminal/Totalterminal or iTerm, this script works very well:

`cd ~/go/to/dir/ && R -e "shiny::runApp("/go/to/dir", launch.browser=TRUE)"`

but as/in a App via Automator, the second Part wont work.

In Automator: run Shell-Script.
Where is the difference of "normal" Terminal and the Terminal used by Automator.
In both /bin/bash

Comment: run shell script is not the same as terminal in automator

Comment: I don't use automator much, but in apple script if you do something out of a canonical comand line (like use R, for example), you must run `tell application "Terminal" activate do shell script "..."`

Comment: nearly perfect ;) but so far applescript has problems with
`R -e 'shiny::runApp("/Users/1/2/3/", launch.browser=TRUE)'`
in AS you need:
`"R -e 'shiny::runApp("/Users/1/2/3/", launch.browser=TRUE)'"`
Its a problem with the marks.

Comment: Yes,I'v try it but always failed. I miss the right psotion for the "\"

Comment: post your applescript that you've embedded into an Applescript Automator action and we can help with the quoted forms, etc.

Comment: `tell application "Terminal"
 activate
 do shell script "cd ~/A/B/C/"
 delay 1
 do shell script "R -e 'shiny::runApp(launch.browser=TRUE)'" in front window
end tell`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Shellscript from Mac Automator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161100/run-shellscript-from-mac-automator)

Comment: # Solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161100/run-shellscript-from-mac-automator

Answer (score 0):

Is `r` on the path in Automator? If not, replace `r` with the full path like `/usr/local/bin/r` (shown by `which r`).