# Run Shellscript from Mac Automator

Tags: macos, bash, automator

In OS X 10.9.5

I wrote a Shell Script (via vim). Save it and navigate to this script and

`sh code.sh`it runs perfect (in iTerm & Total Terminal).

The same command in the same directory produces via Mac Automator always an ERROR. Why?

in Automator and in Terminal.

`echo $SHELL
/bin/bash`

Why is it impossible to run a shellscript via Automator. [image]

Comment: Works for me.  Does `code.sh` expect some input from somewhere?  Can you run it with `sh -x` (or rather, `bash -x`, if it's really properly a Bash script) to see where exactly it's failing?

Comment: Does the file have a trailing newline?  For me, it doesn't print anything, but succeeds; but I have a different version of OSX for testing (some really old one).

Comment: "Gestoppt" doesn't sound like an error proper, though.  Did you stop it manually after some 30 seconds?

Comment: "Gestoppt": it means in German language "STOP". It is not the usual ```can't find lib-x or lib-y```. Only STOP.
The Shell-script itself contains a **RScript**. ```Rscript -e 'shiny::runApp(("/Users/Einstein/Git/RShiny/fooapp"),launch.browser=TRUE)'```

Comment: Well, yes, I get substantially the same message (albeit not in German) if I put `sleep 1000` in the command to run, and press the Stop button after allowing it to run for a while.  So I guess that's what you did as well.

Comment: The information above starkly constracts with the problem description.  It is quite clear then that you don't get this error message if you run a script which contains `echo $SHELL` and that the actual problem (if there is one) is inside the R script.  Nominating this question for closing.

Comment: Not sure about the significance of `launch.browser` but speculating that this is the actual source of your problem.

Comment: ```launch.browser``` isn't the problem. 
I tested several variations of execution the RScript - with and without shell script. Both variations, direct from terminal or as shell script working very well. But from Automator there is always a problem. I have no idea how to identify the difference of Terminal ans Automator-Temrinal (run shell script).

Comment: Try running it with [`--verbose`](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/options.html)?

Comment: No, sorry, ```--verbose```brings no working process. 
I was in good hope that the ```chmod```could save the problem, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 13):

This problem can be solved by adding the following code above your current code:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it's the `cd Desktop` bit.  You can try:

```
(cd ~/Desktop; sh code.sh)
```

However:

- You should make `code.sh` executable so you don't need to invoke it with `sh`.  This is done with `chmod 0755 code.sh`.
- If you need the shell script to work from a certain directory (i.e. the directory where the script is located) then build that into the script so it can be invoked with just `~/Desktop/code.sh`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  dir=$(dirname $0)
  cd $dir
  # do work
  ```

For example:

```
➜  ~  cat tmp/code.sh
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(dirname $0)
cd $dir
ls -l

➜  ~  chmod 0755 tmp/code.sh
➜  ~  tmp/code.sh
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   6 andy  staff    204 Feb 22 18:53 Archives
drwxr-xr-x  11 andy  staff    374 Jun 18 13:59 DerivedData
-rw-r--r--   1 andy  staff    225 May 20 13:44 MyFirstProgram.X
-rwxr-xr-x   1 andy  staff   3072 May 20 13:44 MyFirstProgram.exe
drwxr-xr-x   3 andy  staff    102 Jan  6  2014 bug_reports
-rwxr-xr-x   1 andy  staff     43 Aug  6 14:15 code.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 andy  staff  11539 May 20 08:33 iOS_Team_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision
-rw-r--r--   1 andy  staff   1438 May 20 08:40 ios_development.cer
-rwxr-xr-x   1 andy  staff    272 Aug  5 08:55 script.sh
```

Comment: Thx. this works perfect for any "normal" shell-script.

Comment: @Teletubbi-osx Sorry I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Your example runs perfect! 
My problem: my shell-script contains "material" that is easy to run by iTerm/Terminal  etc. but not from Automator. I recreate this problem with 5 OS X machines (macbook air, macbook pro, iMac; 10.9.4/10.9.5).
Its always the same; works from Terminal doesnt work from Automator.

So it´s obvious that autmator is the problem.
When you execute 
```Rscript -e 'shiny::runApp(("/Users/Einstein/Git/RShiny/fooapp"),launch.browser=TRUE)'``` 
via Terminal, you can see the loading process and the browser opens - perfect. In Automator, no output ...

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

Create two output files:
In Automator:
`env > ~/Desktop/file_1.txt`
in iTerm:
`env > ~/Desktop/file_2.txt`

## DIFF

`diff -y  ~/Desktop/file_1.txt ~/Desktop/file_2.txt`

And, voila, there are interessting differences!
Insert the differences e.g. `export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` to the script, and it works!

Comment: Difference in `PATH` variable between Automator and Terminal is the main cause of this. Automator defaults to `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` while environmental variable would be similar to `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` so Automator is missing `/usr/local/bin`. Exporting `PATH` in Automator script should indeed fix the issue.